# DLL cannot be loaded even though file exists

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll

I'm debugging a .NET desktop app in Visual Studio 2014 CTP on Windows 7 in a VirtualBox VM which uses a managed DLL (probably a wrapper) which in turn uses an unmanaged DLL. Both are in the same directory as the executable. The managed DLL is loaded correctly but when execution reaches a line calling a function from it, an exception is shown that the unmanaged DLL couldn't be loaded: System.DllNotFoundException. However, when I rename the unmanaged DLL and put an empty file there with the name and extension that the unmanaged DLL had, there is also an exception, but a different one: System.BadImageFormatException. Why is the original file ignored when it's supposed to be loaded and how to fix this problem?

Comment: It's probably due to some missing DLL that the unmanged DLL depends upon.